# search lines of a phrase

Tags: string, search

I'm trying to program a grep method to search a text file with a provided user input word. The code will then search each line of the text file, searching for the user input word. If found if will display the line with the word in the correct location surrounded by <> symbols.

If I use the first line of this post as an example if would be-

user input: "a"

output:
Line 1: I'm trying to program  < a > grep method to search < a > text file with < a > provided user input word. The code will

I've already gotten a majority of it written out but it needs to consider for wrapped phrases and multiple phrases in the same line, such as  in my example. What should be the approach?

```
public static void grep(String[] phrases, Scanner words3) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int line = 1;
    boolean found = false;
    String grep;

    System.out.print("\n\n\nPLease enter something to grep: ");
    grep = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");

    while(words3.hasNext() == true) { //check file for remaining lines of text and searches each for user input string
        String currentLine = words3.nextLine();

        if(currentLine.indexOf(grep) == -1) { //change so it accounts for the grep as a wrapped phrase and for multiple matches in the same line
            line++;
            continue;
        }
        else {

            System.out.print("Line " + line + " ");               
            int l = 0;

            while(l < currentLine.length()) {
                if(l == currentLine.indexOf(grep)) {
                    System.out.print("<" + grep + ">" ); 
                    l += grep.length() - 1;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(currentLine.charAt(l));
                }
                l++;
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
            line++;
            found = true;

        }
    }

    if(found == false) {
        System.out.print("[The word <" + grep + "> was not found]\n");
    }


}
```